# If The Father is required to get into Mortis, does that mean that the New Jedi Order’s quest for Mortis is doomed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars

In the Clones Wars Episode “Ghosts of Mortis”, Obi-Wan Kenobi asks The Father that if they were not meant to interfere, then why did The Father bring them to Mortis? That seems to imply (at least to me) that The Father is required to let anyone enter Mortis. Especially since Rex and an entire Venator are unable to find it.

So, does this mean the New Jedi Order’s hunt for Mortis, and the Mortis Dagger, is doomed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact line from the episode is a little more ambiguous. The exchange takes place in the context of The Father telling Obi-Wan that Anakin has gone to confront The Son:

> OBI-WAN: Where's Anakin?
>
> THE FATHER: He came to me for guidance, but at the crossroad, only he can choose. The Force will be his guide now.
>
> OBI-WAN: I don't like this. What have you done?
>
> THE FATHER: I have done nothing. I am merely letting the will
> of the Force take shape.
>
> OBI-WAN: Where has he gone?
>
> THE FATHER: To the well of the dark side.
>
> [...]
>
> OBI-WAN: And how do I get there?
>
> FATHER: You cannot interfere.
>
> OBI-WAN: The way I see it, if we were not supposed to interfere, Ahsoka and I wouldn't be here in the first place.
>
> <sub>(Source: https://subslikescript.com/series/Star_Wars_The_Clone_Wars-458290/season-3/episode-17-Ghosts_of_Mortis)</sub>

In context, The Father is saying that it's the will of the Force that Anakin make a choice on his own, while Obi-Wan is countering that the will of the Force also ensured that he and Ahsoka were there to guide Anakin. Obi-Wan and The Father are disagreeing about what the Force wants, not what The Father wants, and the implication seems to be that it's the Force itself that decides who comes to Mortis, not The Father.

Comment: I personally view it as kind of like those DMT elves drug users see.  It's not real its just hallucinations that is consistent for multiple people.  Like the Daughter didn't really die she's just symbolic of the fall of the Jedi.  If Mortis ever got revisited the family should be back - though again this is just my head canon.